# Decision making with binomial probability

Tags: binomial-distribution

This is an example given in the book . I have attached the snippet of the problem. I can infer straightaway  that when 5 of 20 drives i.e., 25% require repairs within first year  , than we can reject the claim. But I am not able to understand the statement - **"when the probability that 5 or more drive requiring repair is so low, we can reject".**

Appreciate any pointers that  would aid my understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

If **250 out of a 1000** drives were faulty, it's a clear sign something is off with the claim, you have *150 faults* unaccounted for if you take the 10% failure rate at face value.

If **25 out of 100** drives were broken, you need to justify *15 failures*. That's still pretty hard to attribute to bad luck, but it's a little more believable, isn't it?

On the flip side, if **1 out of 2** drives failed, then you have observed an astoundingly high failure rate of **50%**! Before you run off to grab the nearest lawyer, though, this exact result has an 18% ($.1*.9+.9*.1$) chance of happening even if the manufacturer's claim of a 10% failure rate is *perfectly true*.

In other words, you'd expect to see the '50%' failure rate in around one out of every five tests using two drives (and one test in a hundred would see both drives failing) *completely at random* even if the manufacturer's claim was true by sheer luck of the draw, so... not a very good test setup.

Your intuition is good, but if you don't put a number on it, it can lead you to silly places in extreme scenarios. Hence, the probability of seeing the data given the claimed distribution is a better guide than just eyeballing it.

What constitutes a 'low' probability is not well defined; it's not unusual to be some combination of 'eh, good enough' and assessing the risks and costs of being wrong given that probability from a business/ethics/common practice/whatever perspective.

Comment: I am trying to comprehend your answer . could you please let me know how we have 18% (.1∗.9+.9∗.1) .

Comment: If you don't care about the ordering of events, there are two scenarios with 2 parts, 1 failure: FS and SF (where S/F is Success/Failure). p(S)=0.9, p(F)=0.1, both are independent; that gives us the total probability $p(S)*p(F)+p(F)*p(S) = 0.9*0.1+0.1*0.9 = 0.09+0.09 = 0.18$. Two successes is 0.9*0.9, two failures is 0.1*0.1, sum of all cases is 1 as expected.

Comment: Why are rejecting manufacturer's claim When the probability of 5 or more requiring repairs is very small ?

Comment: Thank you . It took this long for me to comprehend

Answer (score 0):

Start by *assuming the manufacturer's claim is true* that only 10% of hard drives require repairs within the first year (in other words, there's a probability of 0.10 that each hard drive they sell will fail within the first year).

If that assumption was true, we'd expect only 2 of the 20 hard drives sold to fail.  But 5 failed, and the probability of 5 or more failing is 0.0432, which is really small. Therefore, one of two things is true: either the manufacturer was lying, or we just got *really, really* unlucky to have 5 of the 20 drivers fail.

In statistics, when the probability of an event is less than 0.05 (like 0.0432 here), we conclude that the assumption made was false (so here, we ***reject the manufacturer's claim.***)

Comment: 0.0432 is the probability of 5 or more drives dailed; not 5 failed. your explanation is that involving hypothesis. This discussion is before the introduction of hypothesis.

Comment: You're correct that 0.0432 the probability of 5 or more drives failing, and I updated my response.  But the rest of what I stated is still true, even if hypothesis testing wasn't formally introduced by that point in the text.

Comment: I would like to understand this without the realms of hypothesis testing and that was the intention of book at this stage